# When is something coordinate independent

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

One defines a critical point of a function $f$ to be a point where all its partial derivatives vanish. The critical points fall into two classes, degenerate and non-degenerate ones. A critical point is non-degenrate if the determinant of the Hessian matrix is non-zero. The Hessian has the property that it does not depend on the choice of coordinates: if different coordinates are chosen the determinant at a point will not change its value. On the other hand the second derivatives of a function are coordinate dependent. Here is an example to illustrate this:

If $f(x,y) = x^2-y^2$ then $f_x = 2x$ and $f_y = -2y$ which are zero at $(0,0)$ and $f_{xx}=2$ and $f_{yy}=-2$. Changing to coordinates $u = x-y$ and $v=x+y$ so that $f(u,v) = uv$ one has still $f_u = v, f_v = u$ which  are zero at $(0,0)$. But now $f_{uu}= f_{vv}=0$.

So I am wondering: when is an expression coordinate independent? Why is the second derivative not coordinate independent but the first is?

Comment: "If different coordinates are chosen the determinant at a point will not change its value." - That's not true. In your own example with $f(x, y) = x^2 - y^2$ the determinant is $-4$ in the first coordinate system and $-1$ in the second. The sign doesn't change though, so the definition of non-degenerateness is fine.

Comment: The first derivatives by themselves are also coordinate-dependent, just like the second derivatives. Although if all of the partial derivatives are $0$, then they are all $0$ in any coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

This boils down to linear algebra.  You can think of the Hessian as a bilinear form, which becomes a matrix of second derivatives once you choose coordinates.  Changing to new coordinates amounts to changing the basis in which the bilinear form is expressed.

Determinant is well-defined as a function of the bilinear form (not just the matrix representing it) and is invariant under basis change.

For what it's worth, trace is also an invariant, so it doesn't depend on choice of coordinates either.

Comment: But the comment on the Q points out that the determinant of the Hessian isn't invariant under basis change. I.e. in the x-y space, it is -4 and in the u-v space it is -1. So I don't think this answer is right...